# A single destructuring assignment to obtain values from the result returned by RegExp.exec()

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

Given the following `findMatches` function that returns a somewhat customized result from [`RegExp.prototype.exec()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec).

#### Demo:

```js
/**
 * Ensures a new RegExp has a specified flag such as the global `g`.
 *
 * @param {String} flags - The string containing the current flag(s).
 * @param {String} flag - The flag to ensure is set, e.g. `g`.
 * @returns {String} The new flag(s) inclcuding the specified flag.
 */
function ensureRegExpHasFlag(flags, flag) {
  return flags.includes(flag) ? flags : `${flags}${flag}`;
}

/**
 * @typedef matchesInfo
 * @desc An Array of Objects with details of each match found.
 * @type {Object[]}
 * @property {String} fullMatch - The full string of characters matched.
 * @property {Number} matchLength - The no. of characters in the matched string.
 * @property {Number} startIndex - The start index for the matched string.
 * @property {Number} endIndex - The end index for the matched string.
 */

/**
 * Find all matches of a pattern in a given string.
 *
 * @param {String} data - The string to match a regular expression against.
 * @param {Object} regExp - The regular expression written as a literal value.
 * @returns {matchesInfo} An Array of Objects with details of each match found.
 */
function findMatches(data, regExp) {
  regExp = new RegExp(regExp, ensureRegExpHasFlag(regExp.flags, 'g'));

  const matchesInfo = [];
  let match;

  while ((match = regExp.exec(data))) {

    const [ fullMatch ] = match;
    const { index: startIndex } = match;

    matchesInfo.push({
      fullMatch,
      matchLength: fullMatch.length,
      startIndex,
      endIndex: startIndex + fullMatch.length
    });
  }

  return matchesInfo;
}

const haystack = 'The quick brown fox jumps over the quick dog';

const needles = findMatches(haystack, /quick/);

console.log(needles)
```

**Note:** The code above currently does return the correct desired result as follows:

> ```
> [
>   {
>     "fullMatch": "quick",
>     "matchLength": 5,
>     "startIndex": 4,
>     "endIndex": 9
>   },
>   {
>     "fullMatch": "quick",
>     "matchLength": 5,
>     "startIndex": 35,
>     "endIndex": 40
>   }
> ]
> ```

#### Question:

Is it possible to refactor the following two lines of destructuring, (found in the body of `while` loop above), to a single destructuring assignment instead?

```js
const [ fullMatch ] = match;
const { index: startIndex } = match;
```

It seems odd to me that the [result returned](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec#Return_value) from `exec()` is both an Array and an Object. There seems to be no [nesting of Objects in the Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Nested_object_and_array_destructuring), so something like the following single destructuring assignment (or variants of it) does not work:

```js
const [ fullMatch, { index: startIndex } ] = match;
```

---

<sub>**Note:** I'm aware of the [`matchAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/matchAll) feature which recently made it to ECMAScript 2020 - but that's not my question :)</sub>

---

Comment: "*It seems odd to me that the result returned from `exec()` is both an Array and an Object.*" - any JS array is an object, the odd thing here is just that it does have a `.startIndex` property.

Comment: @Bergi - yes  _"the odd thing here is just that it does have a `.startIndex` property"_ - however it's named `index` and I wanted to differentiated between that and the `endIndex` (which it doesn't have). Sure _"any JS array is an object"_ however, It does seem odd though that `console.log(Array.isArray(match))` in the body of the `while` loop returns `true`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you don't need the iterable-destructuring here, you just want to access the `0` property of the match result:

```
const { 0: fullMatch, index: startIndex } = match;
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure, it’s possible:

```js
let m = /foo/.exec('seafood');
let { [0]: fullMatch, index: startIndex } = m;

console.log(fullMatch, startIndex);
```

I would not write that, though, or even use destructuring at all with a non-matching property name:

```js
const [ fullMatch ] = match;
const startIndex = match.index;
```